# How to show different image on JavaScript onclick and display the same image on 3rd or 4th click

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, button, random

```js
window.onload = choosePic;
var myPix = new Array("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg");

function choosePic() {
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
  document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];
  document.getElementById("myPicture2").src = myPix[randomNum];
  document.getElementById("myPicture3").src = myPix[randomNum];
}
```

```html
<img src="img.jpg" width="100" height="100" id="myPicture" alt="some image" />
<img src="img.jpg" width="100" height="100" id="myPicture2" alt="some image" />
<img src="img.jpg" width="100" height="100" id="myPicture3" alt="some image" />
<button id="btn" onclick="choosePic()">Click Hear</button>
```

I want to show 3 different images from the array. and on 4th or 5th click want to show the same pic.

Comment: `same pic` mean which one out of first 3?

Comment: Sometime should show img1.jpg, sometime img2.jpg, sometime img3.jpg @brk

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
// gather all <img> elements on page
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
const imgCount = imgs.length;

// the "Click Here" button
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

// array of randomly generated image URLs
let imgUrls = [];
let urlsLength;

// number of button clicks
let clickCount;

// initialize the page
function initialize() {
  clickCount = 0;

  // form array of random image urls from 'picsum.photos'
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  for (let i = 0; i < imgCount * 4; i++) {
    imgUrls.push(
      `https://picsum.photos/id/${randomIndex+i}/100`);
  }
  urlsLength = imgUrls.length;

  // hide all <img> elements
  imgs.forEach(img => {
    img.src = "#";
    img.style.opacity = "0";
  });

  // enable the "Click Here" button
  btn.disabled = false;
}

// handle "Click Here" button
function buttonClick() {
  const iUrlRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * urlsLength);

  if (++clickCount < 4) {
    // show 3 random images
    for (let j = 0; j < imgCount; j++) {
      const iImg = (iUrlRand + j) % urlsLength;
      imgs[j].src = imgUrls[iImg];
      imgs[j].style.opacity = "1";
    }
  } else if (clickCount < 6) {
    // show 1 random image, duplicated in 3 elements
    imgs[0].src = imgUrls[iUrlRand];
    for (let j = 0; j < imgCount; j++) {
      imgs[j].src = imgUrls[iUrlRand];
    }
  }

  if (clickCount === 5) {
    // disable button to prevent more than 5 clicks
    btn.disabled = true;
  }
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #aaa">
  <img src="" width="100" height="100" alt="img 0" />
  <img src="" width="100" height="100" alt="img 1" />
  <img src="" width="100" height="100" alt="img 2" /><br/>
  <button id="btn" onclick="buttonClick()">Click Here</button>
  <button onclick="initialize()">Reset</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Should show random pic before 4 clicks. And on 4 or 5 click Sometime should show img1.jpg, sometime img2.jpg, sometime img3.jpg

Comment: It's not showing the same 3 image in the 4th click. it's just showing 1 image. @terrymorse

Comment: @SharwarAmanSymon That's correct, after 3rd click, it shows 1 image in 1 image element. Do you want it to show the same image in 3 separate image elements? An easy change, done.

Comment: Many Many Thanks.  @terrymorse